# Get the sum of a column for exactly n rows

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-8.0

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    server_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    secret_number INT NOT NULL,
    processing_status VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'UNPROCESSED',
    ts TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```

I want to get the `SUM(secret_number)` of EXACTLY top 5 records `ORDER BY id` which are in UNPROCESSED status. The below query works EXCEPT that it gives me the sum even when there are less than 5 matching records.

```
SELECT SUM(secret_number)
FROM (
    SELECT secret_number
    FROM test
    WHERE processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED' AND server_id = 'R_SERVER'
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
) t1;
```

How can I modify this (or write a new query) that either returns `NULL` when there are less than 5 records matching the criteria? Or, if it can return me the `COUNT` along with `SUM` then in my Python code, I can check if returned count is less than 5, then ignore the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with window functions and aggregation:

```
select sum(secret_number end) as res
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from test t
    where processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED'
) t
where rn <= 5
having count(*) = 5
```

The subquery enumerates the record by `id`; then the outer query ensures that the subquery returned at least 5 records (if not, an empty resultset is returned), and takes the sum of the top 5.

If you do want a `null` value instead of an empty resultset when there are less than 5 records, then:

```
select case when count(*) >= 5 then sum(case when rn <= 5 then secret_number end) end as res
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from test t
    where processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED'
) t
```

Comment: This works perfectly. With this, I don't even have to worry about anything in my Python code

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions based on top of your original query without over complicating stuff:

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 THEN SUM(secret_number) END
-- one row containing sum or null
```

Use `HAVING`:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
-- one row with sum
-- or zero rows
```

Comment: Using ```HAVING``` clause was my attempt before posting the question. ```SELECT SUM(SECRET_NUMBER), COUNT
FROM (SELECT secret_number, processing_status, id, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM test WHERE processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED' AND server_id = 'R_SERVER' 
  GROUP BY processing_status, id, secret_number ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) t1
GROUP BY count;``` However, since ```id``` is the only unique field, and I have to ```GROUP BY``` on other ```SELECT``` fields, it never gave me the desired result. I am not sure about how to use ```CASE``` that you suggested

Comment: replace `SELECT SUM(secret_number)` with the select clause in the answer.

Comment: That worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: This is the final query that either gives the sum or no records: ```SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 THEN SUM(secret_number) END AS count
FROM (SELECT secret_number, processing_status, id, COUNT(*)
        FROM test WHERE processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED' AND server_id = 'R_SERVER'
        GROUP BY processing_status, id, secret_number ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) t1```

Comment: Your final query is confusing. If you've `where`d the result to exactly one server and one status then there you can remove them from group by and select. Not sure what id is doing in the group by either... if it is the primary key then you (usually) don't group on it. In fact, you can remove the entire group by and just select secret_number.

Comment: You are right. Simplified version: ```SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 5 THEN SUM(secret_number) END AS count FROM (SELECT secret_number FROM test WHERE processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED' AND server_id = 'X_R_SERVER' ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) t1;```

Answer (score 2):

> if it can return me the COUNT along with SUM

You can do this using `row_number()` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(secret_number)
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rn
  FROM test
  WHERE processing_status = 'UNPROCESSED'
) AS s
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: Des this return `null` where there are less than 5 matching records?

Comment: No, but will return the count and sum

Comment: Thank you, this at least gives me the required count that I can use in the Python code to exclude the resultset from processing when count is not 5